# Retry a Restangular call in an interceptor

Tags: angularjs, restangular

The official restangular documentation [provides](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setrequestinterceptor) this code sample to retry a request in the ErrorInterceptor:

```
var refreshAccesstoken = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Refresh access-token logic

    return deferred.promise;
};

Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {
    if(response.status === 403) {
        refreshAccesstoken().then(function() {
            // Repeat the request and then call the handlers the usual way.
            $http(response.config).then(responseHandler, deferred.reject);
            // Be aware that no request interceptors are called this way.
        });

        return false; // error handled
    }

    return true; // error not handled
});
```

However, as it says in the comments, the second attempt will not trigger any interceptors because it uses $http directly.

Is there a way to make the second request also go through the Restangular pipeline and execute the ErrorInterceptor?

Comment: you can replace the `$http(response.config).then(responseHandler, deferred.reject);` with restApi call.. Use $http interceptors rather than restangular interceptor, even with restangular. I prefer $http interceptors because all the angularjs api wrappers like restangular internally use $http under the hood...

Comment: The question is **about** switch from `$http` to `Restangular` in the interceptor. Do not confuse `Restangular` with a simple rest call.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the requests made with *Restangular* use promises that have been designed to be resolved only once. You can't resend it in case of rejection.

I don't really know if you want a re-usable `errorInterceptor` or not, but the way the service works don't seems to allow to re-build a *Restangular object* simply from the `response object config`.

One thing you could do is save the reference to your *object* and then use it in the *interceptor*.

You should have your reasons, but I must warn you with this because in case of failure and if it persists, you could end up with an infinite call, since the *Restangular* will always call the `errorInterceptor`.

I've mocked up a little <kbd>[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fBr5gapVkDtqLk8Nlxz?p=preview)</kbd> for the demonstration, just open your network tab and click the button, you should see all the request goes trough there.

Comment: i have a scenario like if i get error code some 200, when i called some post service, the i need to call a service (like get), again need to call the same post service in which i got the error code 200

Answer (score 1):

Using [`async.retry`](https://github.com/caolan/async#retry) may fit to your problem.

Let's assume your asynchronous function is :

```
function apiCall(callback) {
  Restangular.all('items').getList()
    .then(function (res) {
      // all is OK
      callback(null, res);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      if (err.status === 403) {
        // this one will bring async to retry apiMethod
        return callback(err);
      }
      // others errors codes will not call apiMethod again
      callback(null);
    });
}
```

Example using `retry` :

```
// async will try it 3 times
async.retry(3, apiCall, function(err, result) {
  // do something with the result
});
```

[`async.doUntil`](https://github.com/caolan/async#doUntil) could interest you too.

Answer (score 1):

It is too late for an answer, however I found a solution for this, So I am going to mention it here as possible solution.

There is a hint in the following link which says you need to use `restangularizeElement`.

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1022

I am fixing restangular official example as follow:

```
Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {
  if(response.status === 403) {
    refreshAccesstoken().then(function() {
      // instead of using $http, I will use restangularizeElement as follow
      // I still have no idea how is the best method to repeat the request after restangularized it. I am repeating it with a simple get
      var request = Restangular.restangularizeElement('', response.data, url);
      request.get().then(function() {});
    });
    return false; // error handled
  }

  return true; // error not handled
});
```

In this way, if repeated request cause any error, it will be caught in restangular error interceptor again.