# Resend REST Call in Restangular after JWT Refresh

Tags: angularjs, jwt, restangular

I am currently working on a web application that uses a JWT for authentication on all REST calls. The problem we are having is when a customer is performing an action needing a REST call and the JWT is expired, for whatever reason. At that point it kicks back a 401 response, as it should.

The functionality I am looking for is some way to intercept the 401 error, refresh the JWT, and retry the request without sending errors to the user.

The application runs on AngularJS and uses Restangular to handle all of the rest calls. So far I have been looking closely at the setErrorInterceptor as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725896/retry-a-restangular-call-in-an-interceptor/25838928#25838928) and at the Restangular documentation. Using a version of that posted code, I could successfully resend the request and in the .then() portion I had a successful response. However, it seems from the documentation that this method can only return false or true, so I couldn't get at it.

At the moment we have a timer that basically compares the jwt expiration time to the current system time and refreshes the jwt when there are 60 seconds left before expiration. This caused issues when the user's system clock was off compared to the server clock, resulting in a token not being refreshed because the application thought there was more time.

A solution to that specifically would be something like getting the system time, comparing to server time and creating an offset variable, but that doesn't cover all the bases for things that could go wrong. On another topic, checking the JWT before every request is not feasible.

Is there a way within Restangular's interceptors to accomplish the error interception and resending? If not, are there ways outside of it?